# Партиционирование уже существующей таблицы по дате с периодом 1 месяц

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, oracle11g

Есть таблица +20 млн. записей за 2 года. Хочу ее партиционировать по дате, период 1 месяц.

Офф. документацию смотрел и возникли вопросы:

1. обязательно ли для паритициорирования пересоздавать таблицу?
2. во всех примерах партиции создаются в ручную, например:

   ```sql
   PARTITION BY RANGE (time_id)INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH'))
   ( PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-1-2007', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),
     PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-1-2008', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),
     PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-7-2009', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),
     PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-1-2010', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) );
   ```

   , можно как-то автоматизировать этот процесс?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> обязательно ли для паритиционирования пересоздавать таблицу?

Да, существующую не паритиционированную таблицу [можно изменить](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/evolve-nopartition-table.html#GUID-5FDB7D59-DD05-40E4-8AB4-AF82EA0D0FE5) начиная с 12.02. Создайте новую и импортируйте данные:

```sql
create table ptab (id number, time_id date)
partition by range (time_id) interval (numtoyminterval (1,'month'))
(
    partition partdef values less than (date'2000-01-01')
);
```

> партиции создаются вручную ... можно как-то автоматизировать этот процесс?

Да, он уже автоматизирован. При создании таблицы надо создать как минимум только  одну партицию, например, для заведомо старых дат (см. пример выше).

Новые партиции добавятся при вставке автоматически и будут выглядеть где-то так:

```sql
insert into ptab 
    select rownum, date'2019-01-01'+rownum*30
    from xmlTable ('1 to 3')
;  
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats (user, 'ptab')
select partition_name, high_value, num_rows
from user_tab_partitions
where table_name = upper ('ptab') 
;

PARTITION_NAME   HIGH_VALUE                                                   NUM_ROWS
---------------- ---------------------------------------------------------- ----------
PARTDEF          TO_DATE(' 2000-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS',           0
SYS_P2227        TO_DATE(' 2019-02-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS',           1
SYS_P2228        TO_DATE(' 2019-04-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS',           1
SYS_P2229        TO_DATE(' 2019-05-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS',           1
```

Comment: @АнатолийЭрнст А зачем добавлять новые партиции, для каких значений?